# Using dynamic label to give all results in capital letters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, dynamic

I need this dynamic label to give me all the results in capital letters:

```
[dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="Predio" domainlookup="true"]
```

Comment: Welcome to GSE ! It's a lot of GIS software and if you can clarify which one you use ... Simply edit your post and the chance of having an accurate answer will increase !

Comment: Go to symbol property of the label, there is option 'all capital'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FelixIP gave the correct answer in comments.  Just to clarify and to put it into an actual answer (assuming ArcMap):

- Layer 'Properties'
- 'Labels' tab
- 'Symbol' button
- 'Edit Symbol' button
- 'Formatted Text' tab
- Text Case:  'All Caps'

Then click 'OK' several times to confirm/close dialogues.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your support.